# Stored procedure returns negative value

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I'm working with PowerShell code which in call a procedure on database side. The stored procedure returns -1 and I know it's returned by ExecuteNonQuery(). Here is the code (I run it on azure under runbooks,there is no problem with connection) :

```
try {
    $database = 'database1'
    #Write-Output "Starting ...."
    # Create connection to Master DB
    Write-Output "Running on " $database

    $MasterDatabaseConnection =  New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $MasterDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=False;User ID=$userNameSecret ;Password=$passwordSecret ;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
    $MasterDatabaseConnection.Open()

    Write-Output $MasterDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString
    Write-Output "Connection is opened..."

    # Create command
    $MasterDatabaseCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $MasterDatabaseCommand.Connection = $MasterDatabaseConnection
    $MasterDatabaseCommand.CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[truncate_some_tables]"

    Write-Output "COMMAND = " $SQLStatement
    Write-Output "DATABASE COMMAND EXEC TRUNCATE_SOME_TABLES "

    # Execute the query   
    $MasterDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Write-Output "EXECUTING QUERY"
    
} catch {     
    Write-Output -Verbose "Error executing SQL on database [$database] on server [$dataSource]. Statement: `r`n$SQLStatement"
    throw $_.Exception
    Write-Output $_.Exception
} finally {
    # Close connections to DB
    $MasterDatabaseConnection.Close()
    Write-Output "CONNECTION CLOSED"    
}
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[truncate_some_tables]
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [internal].[operation_messages_scaleout];
    TRUNCATE TABLE [internal].[event_message_context_scaleout];
    TRUNCATE TABLE [internal].[event_messages_scaleout];
END
```

Three tables(above) has data and are not empty.

- What should I add to my code to get more information about the error?
- Why it returns -1?
- How can I improve my code?

Add some more information:

[image]

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE does not work if it is used in a foreign key constraint as a referenced table

Comment: What do you mean by "returns"? The `RETURN` status? If a procedure returns a `RETURN` status of anything other than `0` this normally means "failure".

Comment: @Sergey, can you please explain more or send a link about it?

Comment: @Larnu , I mean that when I run the code it returns  'Output' = -1

Comment: Sure. Here it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15    (restrictions)

Comment: @Sergey , Thank you for the link. I've completed the text with an screenshot of three tables structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually running it from SSMS?

You need to use a `try catch` block for some belt 'n braces protection

```
create or alter procedure [truncate_some_tables]
as
set nocount on;

begin try
    truncate table [internal].[operation_messages_scaleout];
    truncate table [internal].[event_message_context_scaleout];
    truncate table [internal].[event_messages_scaleout];
end try
begin catch
    return Error_Number();
end catch
return 0
go
```

Comment: Yes, there is an scheduled job on DB side(SSMS) which runs successfully and I'm trying to automate it on Azure side via power shell code. Can you please show me in my code as example that which part of my code should be completed with try/catch?

Comment: No - don't EAT the error and pass it back as the return value for the stored procedure. Very few rely on the procedure's return value and this approach will not cause the catch block in the script to run.

Comment: @smor The OP is trying to find out what the error is, this is absolutely how you can do so. I have just **tested** this exact scenario by creating 2 tables with a foreign key reference and then a procedure exactly as above to truncate them. Calling the procedure and capturing the return value gives me value 4712. In looking up the error code I find the error is _Cannot truncate table '%.*ls' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint_. I stand by it.

Comment: @sTTu I checked the tables and they just have indexes(please see the screenshot I've added). One thing that I don't understand is when I run ```truncate table [internal].[event_messages_scaleout]``` it completes successfully on DB side. If it was something with FK och index I should get error for it(?)

Comment: When you run it from powershell and get -1, as mentioned in comments above this looks to be the rowsaffected count not an error code, so have you actually tested with rows in a table to see if it does actually truncate or not?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I add to my code to get more information about the error?

You haven't described what error you're getting.  But one thing you might try is to invert the order of the following two lines - as it stands, the Write-Output statement won't be executed.

```
throw $_.Exception
Write-Output $_.Exception
```

> Why it returns -1?

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) returns the number of rows affected by the query, or -1 for queries that don't UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE any rows.

So it's not the stored procedure that's returning -1, it's `ExecuteNonQuery`.  If you want to capture a value returned by a Stored Procedure, you would need to create a parameter with `Direction` set to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`.  The Stored Procedure you show doesn't explicitly return a value, so will return the default value (0).

> How can I improve my code?

That's open-ended and subjective, I'd start by getting it to work the way you want it to.